# Output surrounded by [' and ]' - How to stop?

Tags: python, regex, rss

I am pulling information down from an rss feed. Due to further analysis,, I don't particularly want to use the likes of beautiful soup or feedparser. The explanation is kind of out of scope for this question.

The output is generating the text covered in `['` and `']`. For example

```
Title:
['The Morning Download: Apple Stumbles but Mobile Soars']
Published:
['Tue, 28 Jan 2014 13:09:04 GMT']
```

Why is this output like this? How do I stop this?

```
try:
    #This is the RSS Feed that is being scraped
    page = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/rss/headline?s=aapl'

    yahooFeed = opener.open(page).read()

    try:
        items = re.findall(r'<item>(.*?)</item>', yahooFeed)

        for item in items:
            # Prints the title
            title = re.findall(r'<title>(.*?)</title>', item)
            print "Title:"
            print title

            # Prints the Date / Time Published
            print "Published:"
            datetime = re.findall(r'<pubDate>(.*?)</pubDate>', item)
            print datetime

            print "\n"

    except Exception, e:
        print str(e)
```

I am grateful of any criticism, advise and best practice information.

I'm a Java / Perl programmer so still getting used to Python, so any great resources you know of, are greatly appreciated.

Comment: [`re.findall()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) would return a list.  That is what you're getting.

Comment: Parsing XML with regular expressions will only lead you to pain and suffering. If you're afraid of pulling in external dependencies, *please* at least use one of the excellent XML parsers in the Python standard library. I recommend ElementTree.

Comment: @MaxNoel Brilliant, thanks for the suggestion. Can you please suggest any sources as how to implement Element Tree. The analysis will be within the hyperlink contained in the xml which will require use of regular expressions. Not the analysis into feeds

Comment: ElementTree is very easy to use. Please take a look at its documentation, which has a tutorial and nice examples: http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`re.search`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) instead of [`re.findall`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall), [`re.findall`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) always returns a [`list`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) of all matches.

```
datetime = re.search(r'<pubDate>(.*?)</pubDate>', item).group(1)
```

Note that the difference between [`re.findall`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) and [`re.search`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) is that the former returns a [`list`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)(Python's array data-structure) of all matches, while [`re.search`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) will only return the first match found.

In case of a no match [`re.search`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) returns `None`, so to handle that as well:

```
match = re.search(r'<pubDate>(.*?)</pubDate>', item)
if match is not None:
   datetime = match.group(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, appreciated. Weird nothing is returned when when using .search - can you please explain your code at the bottom to me?

Comment: @user3077627 `re.search` returns `None` in case no match is found, and in that code I am first trying to check the return value of `re.search`, and if it is not `None` then fetch its `group(1)`